# How to delete an object by Keyvalue?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, object, nested, key-value

I am using a python software library called Topologicpy. I have 7 objects. Each one has a dictionary. Each dictionary has a key called "brepStringType" that has a value of either "Face" or "Cell". I want to delete the object that is of brepStringType "Cell", so that I can do further operations on the "Faces". And I want to generalize this so it will work on a script with many more Faces and Cells.

```py
# Retrieve the vertex object list using Graph.Vertices
objectslist = Graph.Vertices(g)
print(type(objectslist))
print(objectslist)
```

## This Returns the following

```
<class 'list'>
[<topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA69B0>, <topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA6B30>, 
<topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA74F0>, <topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA74B0>, 
<topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA7470>, <topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA6DB0>, 
<topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA5230>]
```

```py
for vertexObjects in objectslist: 
    
    d = Topology.Dictionary(vertexObjects)
    keys = Dictionary.Keys(d)
    brepTypeString = Dictionary.ValueAtKey(d, 'brepTypeString')

    print(vertexObjects)
    print(d)
    print(keys)
    print(keys[2])
    print(brepTypeString)
```

## Returns the following

```
<topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA69B0>
<topologic.Dictionary object at 0x00000180C8F46D70>
['brep', 'brepType', 'brepTypeString', 'location', 'timestamp', 'x', 'y', 'z']
brepTypeString
Face
<topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA6B30>
<topologic.Dictionary object at 0x00000180C6E66DF0>
['brep', 'brepType', 'brepTypeString', 'location', 'timestamp', 'x', 'y', 'z']
brepTypeString
Face
<topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA74F0>
<topologic.Dictionary object at 0x00000180C8ED66F0>
['brep', 'brepType', 'brepTypeString', 'location', 'timestamp', 'x', 'y', 'z']
brepTypeString
Face
<topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA74B0>
<topologic.Dictionary object at 0x00000180C8A99C70>
['brep', 'brepType', 'brepTypeString', 'location', 'timestamp', 'x', 'y', 'z']
brepTypeString
Cell
<topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA7470>
<topologic.Dictionary object at 0x00000180C8F4EA30>
['brep', 'brepType', 'brepTypeString', 'location', 'timestamp', 'x', 'y', 'z']
brepTypeString
Face
<topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA6DB0>
<topologic.Dictionary object at 0x00000180C6E66DF0>
['brep', 'brepType', 'brepTypeString', 'location', 'timestamp', 'x', 'y', 'z']
brepTypeString
Face
<topologic.Vertex object at 0x00000180C8AA5230>
<topologic.Dictionary object at 0x00000180C8A9A6B0>
['brep', 'brepType', 'brepTypeString', 'location', 'timestamp', 'x', 'y', 'z']
brepTypeString
Face
```

```py
# How do I delete all objects with key-value brepTypeString "Cell"? 
    if brepTypeString == "Cell": 
        print(brepTypeString)
        # del (????)
```

Comment: Delete from the list? You could iterate the list in reverse, check the brepTypeString, if it's Cell delete using the index.

Comment: Or you could just create a new list `[vertex for vertex in objectslist if 'Cell' == Dictionary.ValueAtKey(Dictionary.Keys(Topology.Dictionary(vertexObjects)), 'brepTypeString')]` really ugly to fit in one line, you would just create the filtered list in your `for vertexObjects in objectslist: `

Comment: @Daviid, thanks for the response.  I tried your single line solution:  [vertexObjects for o in objectslist if 'Cell' == Dictionary.ValueAtKey(Dictionary.Keys(Topology.Dictionary(vertexObjects)), 'brepTypeString')], but it returns an empty list [ ]. Not sure why. I'm still a python beginner. And I'm definitely missing something here on how to iterate over the Topologic.VertexObjects and their nested dictionaries. I was able to solve the problem at this small scale by removing the 'Cell' object by index, but that solution won't work with 500 or so objects with Faces and Cells.